# How to read serial number from NFC tag?

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, core-nfc

There is how I read NFC tag info:

```
func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCNDEFTag]) {
    
    
    // Connect to the found tag and perform NDEF message reading
    let tag = tags.first!
    
    
    session.connect(to: tag, completionHandler: { (error: Error?) in
        
        tag.queryNDEFStatus(completionHandler: { (ndefStatus: NFCNDEFStatus, capacity: Int, error: Error?) in

            tag.readNDEF(completionHandler: { [self] (message: NFCNDEFMessage?, error: Error?) in
                
                for record in message!.records {
                    print("Type name: \(record.typeNameFormat)")
                    print("Payload size: \(record.payload)")
                    print("Type size: \(record.type)")
                    print("Identifier: \(record.identifier)")

                    print("Payload: " + String(data:record.payload, encoding: .utf8)!)
                    
                }
                
                
                session.invalidate()
            })
        })
    })
}
```

But identifier is always 0 bytes and empty.
How I can read kind of unique identifier or serial number?

Answer (score 2):

NFC tags don't have a unique identifier or serial number, they have an ID that is not guaranteed to be unique.

The Ndef record.identifier you are printing from the [Ndef spec](https://github.com/haldean/ndef/blob/master/docs/NFCForum-TS-NDEF_1.0.pdf) is:-

> The optional payload identifier allows user applications to identify the payload carried within an NDEF record

It is an identifier to help apps determine what type of data is stored in the Ndef structure, it supplements the Payload Type.

To get the non unique ID try printing `tag.identifier` this might return a hex string. But because this is non unique, it should not be used for anything related to security (for some NFC devices the ID is a random hex number, or it can be programmed to be a specific hex number)

Comment: im using this tool to test my read/write https://apps.apple.com/us/app/nfc-tools/id1252962749. where is "serial number" field came from?

Comment: That is the non unique 14443-3 anti-collision ID which should be in the `tag.identifier` that can also some times be a 4 byte Hex number instead of a 7 byte one.

Comment: tag is NFCNDEFTag and there is nothing like identifier

Comment: NDEF is just a standard data format on top of a number of different types for hardware. You can put any data you want in the Ndef format, there are a number of different standard sub formats like URL, Text, as well basic and open format. If you want to uniquely identify a particular Tag you need to cryptographically secure your own unique data.

Comment: ok, thanks for clarification.

Comment: I should point out that for non security critical applications it is fairly likely you won't see the same ID, but as there is hardware available where the ID is set by the user then the ID cannot be used for anything that needs any level of security.

Comment: got it. thanks.